# Azure Active Directory and intranet websites

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to use Azure Active Directory authentication with an intranet website?

I have a website that is only going to be available on my local network. I do not want this to be public. However, when I perform a test login using AAD and OAuth2 it wants to perform a redirect to a specific URL. Is it possible to do what I want or does this only work for public facing websites?

Comment: The redirect URL only needs to point at something your browser can reach. AAD does not have to be able to reach it. Have you tried implementing auth yet?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried to implement auth but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. I've got it setup to redirect to http://localhost:53942/login.html but it just comes back with a "Connection to server failed" message.

Comment: That's how all my development app reply URLs are setup. And you are running the app on your PC?

Comment: Yes. There are two total projects. Project A is the Web API. Project B is the Single Page Application. Both are running in IIS Express via Visual Studio. When I attempt to login Fiddler is picking up an HTTP 200 message but there's no actual response back. However, if I open the login link directly in Chrome it redirects me and I see the auth token in the URL.